# Which travis CI build images boot the fastest?

Tags: bash, performance, build, travis-ci

I have a bare GitHub repo with a bash script that prints hello world.

The travis config is simple

```
script:
  - ./hello_world.sh
```

This build took 24 seconds to complete. Is there a quicker way to build this? After all, all I'm doing is printing a string, I feel 24 secs is  high.

Comment: Please add your Update as an answer instead, to resolve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/) they list typical bootup times of their various vms:

```
Ubuntu Precise 20-50s
Ubuntu Trusty 1-6s
Ubuntu Trusty (Virtual machine on GCE) 20-50s
OSX 60-90s
```

So if you have a project that does a simple build using bash script, Ubuntu Trusty is the way to go (at the moment) with quick 1 to 6 second boot up time.